# Finish an activity,get string typed result from a class and use that result to another activity

Tags: android

I'm new in android environment and started a Software development project, so my knowledge is too few in it. I need help in detail.

Problem details:

Project is on ANDROID OCR code source from github Robert m.theis

currently it's outcome is - while i take an image of any written text,it retrieves quite exact output using tesseract engine as text and search in internet.

my work is -
use the text string (digits ) and call to a phone operator.
my project name is automated mobile card recharging system.

so that i took result text from a method getText() class named OcrResult.java and put into my own activity. But i don't know why this don't working in real device.

it builds, run in emulator, but in real device at least it should show messages! But it doesn't.

i also added in manifest.xml file as (angel braces are remover here)
under activity
    activity android:name="edu.sfsu.cs.orange.ocr.call.CallManager"

under application
    uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"

here my code is

```
package edu.sfsu.cs.orange.ocr.call;
import edu.sfsu.cs.orange.ocr.OcrResult;
import edu.sfsu.cs.orange.ocr.CaptureActivity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CallManager extends Activity
 {

  public static final String preString = "*111*";
  public static final String postString = "#";

  //to store retrieved digits
  String finalString;

  //to get text result from ocr result
  OcrResult getStringResult = new OcrResult();
  String middleString  = getStringResult.getText();

  //if it fails to scan desired digit,call the process again
  CaptureActivity tryProcessAgain = new CaptureActivity();


  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  }

  public void setString(String  x)
    {
      middleString = x;
    }

  public String getString( String toBeInserted)
    {

      if(toBeInserted.length() == 16)
       {

         int counter = 0;
         char [] insertHere  = new char[16];

         for(int verifier = 0; verifier < 16; verifier ++)
          {
            insertHere[verifier] = toBeInserted.charAt(verifier);
            if(!Character.isDigit(insertHere[verifier]))
                 {
                   break;
                 }
            counter ++;
          }

         if(counter == 16)
          {

            finalString = preString + toBeInserted + postString;
            return finalString;
          }

         else
          {
           // @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            //Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, " number scan invalid.....OCR failed. Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            //toast.show();
            return middleString;
          }
       }

         else
         {
            //@SuppressWarnings("unused")
            //Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, " number scannin invalid...OCR failed. Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            //toast.show();
           return middleString;
         }
    }


  public void CallToOperator(String callMe)
  {
      Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this,finalString,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
      toast.show();
      //Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(this,middleString,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
      //toast1.show();



      if(callMe == finalString)
        {
          try 
          {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + finalString)));
          }
          catch (Exception e) 
          {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }

        else
        {
            tryProcessAgain.onShutterButtonPressContinuous();
        }

  }

 }
```

Comment: "i don't know why this don't working."<--Explain . Are there erorrs in logcat?

Comment: There are so many problems in this code that it is impossible, for me at least, to work out what is going on.  It won't even compile as it is.  However, I suspect that (callMe == finalString) is the problem.  It should be (callMe.equals(finalString)).  To begin, please format your code properly so that all of the braces line up correctly and that all if statements are correctly indented.

Comment: For example,  if(!Character.isDigit(insertHere[verifier]))
              break;
            counter ++;
          } is broken.  Where is the opening brace?

Comment: although my problem is not solved,but Simon helped me,thanks man!